# How to store multiple entries for each student using dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, hierarchical-data

Here is the problem statement:

There is a record of 'n' students, each record having name of student, percent marks obtained in Maths, Physics and Chemistry. The user enters an integer 'n' followed by names and marks for the 'n' students. I am required to save the record in a dictionary data type. The user then enters name of a student and you are required to print the average percentage marks obtained by that student, correct to two decimal places.
what I have tried so far:

```
num_students = int(raw_input("Please enter number of students:"))
print "you entered %s students" %num_students
student_info = {}
student_data = ['studentname', 'mathmarks', 'physicsmarks', 'chemistrymarks']
for i in range(0,num_students):
    for entry in student_data:
        student_info[entry] = raw_input(entry )
print student_info
print"please enter student name"
name = raw_input("student name")
if student_info['studentname'] == name:
    print "Average student marks:", (int(student_info['mathmarks']) + int(student_info['physicsmarks']) + int(student_info['chemistrymarks']))/3
else:
    print"please enter valid name"
```

This code is working is num_students = 1, However if num_students >1 the code fails.

I am unable to save the entry of each student in dictionary.

I am pretty new to python, would be glad if any one can help me with this.

Comment: The problem is that you have a dictionary that holds the information for one student. What you need is to create a dictionary that has the student name as a key, and the value of each key is a dictionary that stores the other values.

Comment: Here's a hint towards the solution: Each of the n students has 3 different courses. But you currently store each record directly into the dict `student_info[entry]`, so the most recent record overwrites any previous. You'll need a dict-of-dict, or dict-of-list, or some other data structure. Also, check out `collections.defaultdict`, it will help here.

Comment: Your inner for loop is always setting the same tuple

Comment: By the way, this may be more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com than SO. At least, check out CodeReview, it's neat.

Comment: @smci [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) is explicitly for code which works as intended--this code does not work as intended.

Comment: Oh thanks @nhgrif. The OP can and still should read CodeReview to learn from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you need to create a nested dictionary with name as values and another dict as keys, in pretty way the nested dict may look like:

```
{
    'anmol': {'chemistrymarks': 3, 'physicsmarks': 2, 'mathmarks': 1},
    'uppal': {'chemistrymarks': 6, 'physicsmarks': 5, 'mathmarks': 4}
}
```

So you need to add the following lines to create a nested dictionary.

```
num_students = int(raw_input("Please enter number of students:"))
print "you entered %s students" %num_students
student_info = {}
student_data = ['Math marks : ', 'Physics marks : ', 'Chemistry marks : ']
for i in range(0,num_students):
    student_name = raw_input("Name :")
    student_info[student_name] = {}
    for entry in student_data:
        student_info[student_name][entry] = int(raw_input(entry)) #storing the marks entered as integers to perform arithmetic operations later on.
#print student_info
print"Please enter student name ?"
name = raw_input("Student name : ")
if name in student_info.keys():
    print "Average student marks : ", str(sum(student_info[name].values())/3.0)
else:
    print"please enter valid name"
```

Comment: would you please tell me what this line does exactly?:
student_info[student_name] = {}

Comment: It will create a new empty dictionary for each input name by the user , to sore the marks for various subjects .

Comment: {} is another way of writing dict(),the initializer for a dictionary. So that line is initializing a dictionary in student_info dictionary under key student_name

Answer (score 0):

```
  #youcan use print stmts. acording to your problem
 n = raw_input()
    grades = []
    for entry in range(int(n)):
        grades.append([i for i in raw_input().split()])
    query = raw_input()

    # Find list where first item matches name in query and
    # assign grades to queryResult
    queryResult = [x[1:] for x in grades if x[0] == query]

    total = 0
    scores = 0

for x in queryResult:
    for y in x:
        total += float(y)
        scores += 1
print "%.2f" % (float(total/scores))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Another way
num_of_student = int(raw_input())
dir_student = {}

for i in range(0,num_of_student):
    student_info = raw_input()
    name = student_info.split()
    dir_student[name[0]] = [float(name[1]),float(name[2]),float(name[3])]

find_name = raw_input()
if dir_student.has_key(find_name):
    print "{0:.2f}".format(sum(dir_student[find_name])/3.0)
```